# "connection refused" error when calling Servlet running in localhost Tomcat from Android app

Tags: java, android, tomcat, servlets, httpurlconnection

I am trying to access a **Servlet** method through my **Android app**.
The Servlet is running on **localhost**, on a **Tomcat v8** server.
When I use the **Emulator**, it works just **fine**.
But when I am using a real device, i am getting a **`Connection to http://10.0.2.2:8080 refused`** error.
The android device is connected to my laptop, where Tomcat runs.

I propably have to **configure tomcat to allow incoming connections** from another device (my android device) in the same network? (I don't know how)

Android code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8080/DistributionLogisticsOptimizer/Login");
        String responseText = "";
        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",mEmail));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mPassword));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            /* execute */
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity rp = response.getEntity();
            responseText=readContent(response);
            } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseText;
```

I have also given internet permission to the android manifest

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="14"
android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

This is the Tomcat configuration

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>

<Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>

  <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"/>

  <Context docBase="DistributionLogisticsOptimizer" path="/DistributionLogisticsOptimizer" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:DistributionLogisticsOptimizer"/></Host>
</Engine>
```

Comment: Do you have a firewall?

Comment: Is the real device on the same Wifi as your laptop?

Comment: It is not a firewall issue.
Yes, the android device is on the same wifi as my laptop